# Overriding instantiateItem(...) won't compile

Tags: java, android

I am trying to use a PageAdapter. I found out that `public Object instantiateItem( View pager, int position )` has been deprecated. So I am trying up update but ran into a problem. The new definition changes the deceration to `public Object instantiateItem( ViewPager pager, int position )`, when I do this and push it to my device the app crashed.

Here is my logcat output.

> 12-26 19:24:30.701: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(25431): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>           java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Required method instantiateItem was not overridden
>           at android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter.instantiateItem(PagerAdapter.java:175)
>           at android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter.instantiateItem(PagerAdapter.java:110)
>           at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.addNewItem(ViewPager.java:649)
>           at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:783)
>           at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1016)

So I added `@Override` to the method call, but when I compile it ,using maven, I get the following output that corresponds to my method.

> Chronos/ChronosApp/src/com/kopysoft/chronos/view/ClockViewer.java:[67,4] error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype

I am at a lose as what to do. Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

The entire code can be found here: http://pastebin.com/da5Kqcmg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The runtime code in PagerAdapter.instantiateItem() is throwing the exception because it wants you to override that. So make sure you are overriding the method that is throwing the exception. You probably just want to switch your code back to overriding the deprecated method since that's what your runtime library is expecting.

Might it be possible that you have an older runtime you are running with?

Comment: I did that that seems to have fixed the problem. I am using the most up-to-date version of the compatibility library (which defines the Object). Is that what you mean?

Comment: Yeah, I don't know anything at all about the Andriod stuff. I only know about the Java stuff and the pattern. So I'm not sure why they have deprecated a method, but still require you to use it. It's probably their bug somewhere.